# Java Program imports data using sqoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I have created a web application(JSP) to extract data from mysql database to HDFS.In my Java code, I have used sqoop import command to achieve my requirement. The program executed successfully but the extracted data written to normal unix file system instead of hdfs.

Can anyone let me know how to provide hdfs file system path in sqoop import command?

```
    package com.archival.da;
    import java.sql.*;

    public class DataImportSetup {

static int status=0;

public static int importsetup(String policy_id){


    Connection con=GetCon.getCon();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT  
                   CON.SERVER,CON.PORT,CON.DB,CON.USER,
                   CON.PWD,POLICY.SQL_TEXT FROM POLICY 
            JOIN CONNECTION AS CON ON POLICY.C_ID=CON.C_ID WHERE POLICY.ID=?");
        ps.setString(1,policy_id);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        String ServerNm =   
                    "jdbc:mysql://"+rs.getString(1)+":
                    "+rs.getString(2)+"/"
                    +rs.getString(3);
        String ConUser=rs.getString(4);
        String ConPass=rs.getString(5);
        String SqlText=rs.getString(6);

        String[] str={"import","--connect",ServerNm,"--hadoop-mapred- home","/ms/hadoop-1.2.0", "--query", SqlText , "--target-dir", "/user/root/city","--username", ConUser, "--password", ConPass,"--split-by","id"};
       status=Sqoop.runTool(str);
        System.out.println(status);

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;

}

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's writing to the local file system instead of HDFS because the default file system is local unless otherwise configured. You can configure this to be HDFS using SqoopOptions - see this question / answer for an example:

- [How can I execute Sqoop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918923/how-can-i-execute-sqoop-in-java)

Specifically you need to locate and pass the location of your clusters core-site and hdfs-site xml files:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

Comment: Hello Chris, I used sqoop options and getting error on  
        new ImportTool().`run(options)`;

 The method run(SqoopOptions) in the type ImportTool is not applicable for the arguments (SqoopOptions)

My configurations

Hadoop 1.2.0

Sqoop 1.4.3

Can you please help on this issue?

Comment: Check the package of your `SqoopOptions` - the ImportTool expects a type of `com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions`

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have imported from com.cloudear.sqoop.SqoopOptions and It is working now.I am able to load data to hdfs file system now. I have one more question. Can I give the target file name(not directory) to load the data?

Comment: I'm not sure about that - best to post another question