# Master table data updates in Hive

Tags: hive, sqoop

Can anyone please tell me the process of incremental updates in Hive.
Actually i would like to understand with the help of Hive, how do we manage the master data table.

If everyday there are new set of records coming to get inserted into hive table.
In the new set of records there could be new keys, there could be existing keys which need an update.

I found some information at the [link](http://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/).

Can any one please guide me.

Comment: There is a similar question, see link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679199/hive-table-data-management/38727862#38727862

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute Sqoop in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918923/how-can-i-execute-sqoop-in-java)